# Css display:grid column become hidden on smaller screen devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-grid, mobile-devices

I have the following html page :

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  /*font-size: 55px;*/
}

.main>div {
  height: 200px;
}

.main>div:first-child {
  border: solid 3px red;
}

.main>div:last-child {
  border: solid 3px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    contents 1
  </div>
  <div>
    contents 2
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Expected result on normal screens]
And the result is fine and as I am expecting(the blue div has as twice width as the red div). But when I change the screen size to less than `246px` the blue div started to hide under the browser edge :

[image: Some portion of the blue div is hidden on screens less than 246px]

How can I keep the ratio of two div in smaller screen sizes ?

**Update:** font-size has been removed but the problem still exists.

Comment: I cannot see the problem here.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? 246 is comparatively small :(

Comment: Do you have any code that we aren't seeing? Altough I wouldn't worry too much, the smallest modern screen is about 320px.

Comment: @Derek.W parts of the div is hidden  and I want it the be visible in the screen like the normal one .

Comment: Have you run the snippet? If the screen width is not tiny, it works with no problems.

Comment: I run the exact same code on chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add viewport meta tag and also clean up initial margin and padding of html and body tags

final codes should be as follow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        .main {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        }

        .main>div {
            height: 200px;
        }

        .main>div:first-child {
            border: solid 3px red;
        }

        .main>div:last-child {
            border: solid 3px blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div>
            contents 1
        </div>
        <div>
            contents 2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```